# Oracle query not working in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, inner-join

I have a query which I am using for displaying data in front end. The issue is the query is working fine if I run with simple parameters and it fetches the data, but when the same is run through the stored procedure it does not bring any data.

Below is the simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NVL(STM.SERVICE_TYPE,'-')SERVICETYPE, NVL(SM.SERVICE_NAME,'-')SERVICENAME, NVL(SM.URL,'-')URL, NVL(SM.MXD,'-')MXD, NVL(SD.SERVER_TYPE,'-')SERVERTYPE, NVL(SD.LAYER,'-')LAYER
    FROM SERVICES_MASTER SM
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_DETAILS SD
              ON SM.SERVICE_ID = SD.SERVICE_ID
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_TYPES_MASTER STM
              ON SM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID = STM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID
    WHERE SM.SERVICE_NAME LIKE '%SNOCAlarmBoundary%';
```

The below is the stored procedure one

```
STREX:='SELECT DISTINCT NVL(STM.SERVICE_TYPE,''-'')SERVICETYPE, NVL(SM.SERVICE_NAME,''-'')SERVICENAME, NVL(SM.URL,''-'')URL, NVL(SM.MXD,''-'')MXD, NVL(SD.SERVER_TYPE,''-'')SERVERTYPE, NVL(SD.LAYER,''-'')LAYER
    FROM SERVICES_MASTER SM
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_DETAILS SD
              ON SM.SERVICE_ID = SD.SERVICE_ID
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_TYPES_MASTER STM
              ON SM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID = STM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID                 
         WHERE SM.'|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
 OPEN P_RETURN FOR STREX USING VAL;
```

why it's not working in second case and what should I do to work it

**update**

```
PROCEDURE FILTER_SEARCH_DATA
  (
P_SEARCH_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,
P_PARAM_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,
P_OPERATOR IN NVARCHAR2,
P_TEXTVAL IN NVARCHAR2,
P_RETURN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
 ) 
 AS

 STR NVARCHAR2(400):='';
 STROP NVARCHAR2(400):='';
  STREX VARCHAR2(4000):='';
 VAL NVARCHAR2(4000);

 BEGIN
 IF (P_OPERATOR = 'LIKE') THEN
     val := '%' || UPPER(P_TEXTVAL) ||'%';
 ELSE
   val := UPPER(P_TEXTVAL) ;
END IF;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STR'|| STR);
  IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'Application' THEN   
   STREX:='SELECT DISTINCT NVL(AM.APPLICATIONNAME,''-'')APPLICATIONNAME, NVL(AD.URLPATH,''-'')URL, NVL(AM.PROJECTNO,''-'')PROJECTNO, NVL(AM.VSS_FOLDER_LOC,''-'')VSSFOLDERLOC,
         NVL(AU.NAME, ''-'')SPOCUSER, NVL(AUR.NAME,''-'')REQUESTEDBY, NVL(AUD.NAME,''-'')DELIVERYMANAGER             
           FROM APPLICATION_MASTER AM 
                INNER JOIN APPLICATION_DETAILS AD
                   ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AD.APP_MST_ID 
                INNER JOIN APPUSER_UMS AU
                   ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AU.APP_USERID    
                   INNER JOIN APPUSER_UMS AUR
                 ON AUR.APP_USERID = AM.REQUESTED_BY_APPUSRID  
                 INNER JOIN  APPUSER_UMS AUD
                      ON AUD.APP_USERID = AM.DELIVERY_MANAGER_APPUSRID  
          WHERE AM.'|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
 OPEN P_RETURN FOR STREX USING VAL;

 END IF;

  IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'Services' THEN   
 STREX:='SELECT DISTINCT NVL(STM.SERVICE_TYPE,''-'')SERVICETYPE, NVL(SM.SERVICE_NAME,''-'')SERVICENAME, NVL(SM.URL,''-'')URL, NVL(SM.MXD,''-'')MXD, NVL(SD.SERVER_TYPE,''-'')SERVERTYPE, NVL(SD.LAYER,''-'')LAYER
    FROM SERVICES_MASTER SM
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_DETAILS SD
              ON SM.SERVICE_ID = SD.SERVICE_ID
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_TYPES_MASTER STM
              ON SM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID = STM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID                             
          WHERE SM.'|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
 OPEN P_RETURN FOR STREX USING VAL;     

END IF;

 IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'Layers' THEN   
 STREX:='SELECT NVL(SERVER_TYPE,''-'')SERVERTYPE, NVL(LAYER,''-'')LAYER, 
NVL(FEATURECLASS,''-'')FEATURECLASS 
          FROM SERVICE_DETAILS
          WHERE '|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
 OPEN P_RETURN FOR STREX USING VAL;     

END IF;

IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'Dbitem' THEN   
STREX:='SELECT NVL(DM.DB_ITEMNAME,''-'')DBITEMNAME, NVL(DM.SCHEMAOWNER,''-'')SCHEMAOWNER, NVL(DT.DBITEMTYPE,''-'')DBITEMTYPE
             FROM DATABASE_ITEMMASTER DM
           INNER JOIN DBITEMTYPE DT
   ON DM.DB_ITM_ID = DT.DB_ITEMTYPE_ID
          WHERE DM.'|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
 OPEN P_RETURN FOR STREX USING VAL;     

END IF;

END FILTER_SEARCH_DATA;
```

Comment: Provide stored procedure and procedure call

Comment: I take it you've tried running the sql statement from the strex variable that you're outputting via dbms_output? Does it run as expected when you run it manually?

Comment: @I3rutt: updated the question

Comment: @Boneist: yes almost it runs properly.. i have updated the question with full procedure.

Comment: `P_PARAM_TYPE`, `P_OPERATOR ` in your example - have no value ...

Comment: @Plirkee: `SM.SERVICE_NAME` is my param_type

Comment: @VVVV "almost it runs properly" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Boneist I mean it runs for `IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'Application'` but not working for `IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'Services'`

Comment: @VVVV "not working"...? You get an error? No data returned? Something else?

Comment: @Boneist: no not an error. just no data returned

Comment: @VVVV that meas that something is wrong / different with your joins, your data, your parameter values - I doubt that we can help you with that - there is no way for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Plirkee: if join would have been the problem then the simple query should not have work but it is working. I guess the issue is in `:PARAM`

Comment: @Plirkee: when i search with `NOC` the result is returned but when I do the same thing with `SNOCAlarmBoundary` it does not return the data

Comment: @Boneist:  when i search with `NOC` the result is returned but when I do the same thing with `SNOCAlarmBoundary` it does not return the data .. something helpful ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so here comes just a wild guess

(As I mentioned before - we do not have enough information to safely pinpoint the source of your problem).

**Try the following**:

```
 IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'Services' THEN   
 STREX:='SELECT DISTINCT NVL(STM.SERVICE_TYPE,''-'')SERVICETYPE, NVL(SM.SERVICE_NAME,''-'')SERVICENAME, NVL(SM.URL,''-'')URL, NVL(SM.MXD,''-'')MXD, NVL(SD.SERVER_TYPE,''-'')SERVERTYPE, NVL(SD.LAYER,''-'')LAYER
    FROM SERVICES_MASTER SM
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_DETAILS SD
              ON SM.SERVICE_ID = SD.SERVICE_ID
          INNER JOIN SERVICE_TYPES_MASTER STM
              ON SM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID = STM.SERVICE_TYPE_ID                             
          WHERE UPPER(SM.'|| P_PARAM_TYPE || ') ' || P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';
```

So what I changed is that now the `upper` is part of the query string. 
I'm guessing that, that was your initial intention (as  `val` is always upper case).

Comment: yes, now it worked.. so what was the root cause of it ??

Comment: 1. your `:param` is always filled with upper case values (`val := '%' || UPPER(P_TEXTVAL) ||'%';`) 2. however your `P_PARAM_TYPE` column's values were not upper cased  so you where doing `where`   `SNOCAlarmBoundary like '%SNOCALARMBOUNDARY%'` which is of course false.  The `upper` in query string fixed it. Don't forget to accept and up-vote. Good luck.